# How to implement a thread-safe class with a setter and a getter function where the frequency of using setter is way higher than getter

Tags: java, multithreading

Let's say we want a thread-safe class called Adder, and there is an add function and a get function

```java
class Adder {
    int counter;
    public void add(int a) counter += a;
    public int get() return counter;
```

Right now it is apparently not thread safe. Now given that the frequency of using add() function is 80% and using get() is 20%. Also, we allow getting a counter with a lag so the get function does not need to be thread safe. How should we implement this? Apparently adding synchronized keyword to add() isnt a good solution since too many threads will try to obtain the lock and there will a race condition.

Also, the add() function should always be successful (meaning that you cannot use non-blocking locking)

Comment: *"Apparently adding synchronized keyword to add() isnt a good solution since too many threads will try to obtain the lock and there will a race condition."* What race condition? Unless you're running into actual performance problems, [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) is probably the easiest solution.

Comment: You may want to [edit] the question with complete interview question...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov This is the full description of the question.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Using synchronized keyword means you are adding a blocking lock to this method. Based on my understanding, CPU is working in a time shared manner. When a thread failed to obtain the lock, it will be hang up to the task queue and wait for being able to obtain the lock again. Since add() function take less time than acquiring the lock, using a blocking lock isnt a good choice. As you said later, AtomicInteger uses non-blocking locking solution on this question. So based on my understanding, this is why using syncronized keyword is bad in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this problem with `AtomicInteger` in Java:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Adder {

    private final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public int add(int delta) {
        return counter.addAndGet(delta);
    }

    public int get() {
        return counter.get();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are willing to allow imperfections in `get`, and the frequency of additions is much higher than of queries, use [`LongAdder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/LongAdder.html).

> This class is usually preferable to AtomicLong when multiple threads update a common sum that is used for purposes such as collecting statistics, not for fine-grained synchronization control. Under low update contention, the two classes have similar characteristics. But under high contention, expected throughput of this class is significantly higher, at the expense of higher space consumption.

Comment: That sounds like the answer interviewer is looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

Using the `synchronized` keyword should not cause any problems. The whole point of `synchronized` is to add thread safety.

If you want a more specific solution, I would try using either `AtomicInteger` or `ReadWriteLock`.

`ReadWriteLock` Solution :

```java
class ThreadSafeAdder {
    private ReadWriteLock lock;
    private int counter;

    public ThreadSafeAdder() {
        lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
        counter = 0;
    }

    public int get() {
        try {
            lock.readLock().lock();
            return counter;
        } finally {
            lock.readLock().unlock();
        }
    }

    public void set(int a) {
        try {
            lock.writeLock().lock();
            counter = a;
        } finally {
            lock.writeLock().unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

`AtomicInteger` does the same thing as the above solution, it just hides all the thread safety code... (As seen in @kamaci's answer)